# AWS Elastic beanstalk - Could not upload file: unknown exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

getting Could not upload file: unknown exception while uploading Spring boot jar file. Any one also facing this issue on AWS beanstalk

Comment: Can you be more specific, when this exactly happens? Do you get any other error messages?

Comment: it was resolved after a day automatically, was due to some issue at aws end

Comment: If it does not resolve, Put your jar file in Aws S3 bucket and upload from there instead of Local disk